# Establishing set theoretic identities

Tags: real-analysis

> I want to prove that  $$ \bigcup_{A \in \mathcal{P}(X)} A = X, \;
>  \text{and} \; \bigcap_{A \in \mathcal{P}(X)} A = \varnothing $$

#### Attempt:

For the first one, If $Y \in \bigcup_{A \in \mathcal{P}(X)} A$, then $Y = A$  for some $A \in \mathcal{P}(X)$. But, $A \subseteq X$, thus $Y \subseteq X$. Conversely, since $X \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ and if $Y \in X$, we have know there exists and element in the power set in which $Y$ belongs, so by definition $Y \in \bigcup_{A \in \mathcal{P}(X)} A$.

As for the other identity, assume the intersection is $\mathbf{not}$ empty, so there is some $Y$ inside of it. So, $Y$ can be any $A \in \mathcal{P}(X)$. In particular, it must be $Y = \varnothing$. Contradiction.

Is this an enough proof? Any suggestion/improvement would be greatly appreciated.

#### Update with suggestion:

Let $x \in \bigcup_{A \in \mathcal{P}(X)} A$, then $x \in A$ for some $A \in \mathcal{P}(X)$. Since $A \subseteq X$, then $x \in X$. Conversely, if $x \in X$, then since $X$ is an element of $\mathcal{P}(X)$, it means that $x \in \bigcup_{A \in \mathcal{P}(X)} A$.

For the other identity, let $x \in \bigcap_{A \in \mathcal{P}(X)} A$ so $x$ is in every $A \in \mathcal{P}(X)$. choose $A \in \varnothing$ and we obtain the result.

Comment: It's mostly said in the answer below, but it's worth writing explicitly: the condition for an element to be in a union is as follows: we have that $y\in \bigcup_{A\in P}A$ exactly when $y\in A$ for some $A\in P$. Your error is essentially to replace one of these memberships with equality (i.e. you have $y=A$ instead of $y\in A$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear in your proof whether $Y$ is an element or a set (it seems to switch roles). To show containment in both directions, you must work with *elements* of both sides.

So for the first direction, let $x \in \bigcup_{A \in \mathcal{P}(X)}A$. Then $x \in A$ for some $A \in \mathcal{P}(X)$. Can you show that $x \in X$?

For the backward direction, let $x \in X$. You need to show there exists $A \in \mathcal{P}(X)$ such that $x \in A$ (and hence $x \in \bigcup_{A \in \mathcal{P}(X)}A$). What $A$ should you choose?

Your second proof is not very clear either. Again you should take an *element* $x \in \bigcap_{A \in \mathcal{P}(X)}A$. This means $x$ is in every $A \in \mathcal{P}(X)$. Can you find a particular such $A \in \mathcal{P}(X)$ which cannot contain $x$, yielding a contradiction?

Comment: Hi, thakns for reply. I have updated my question with your suggestions. Does it look better now?

Comment: Much better! For the second proof, I might say something more like "In particular, taking $A =\varnothing$, we must have $x \in \varnothing$, which is a contradiction. Hence $\bigcap_{A \in \mathcal{P}(X)}A$ must be empty." You could also prove the result more directly by noting that $\varnothing$ is one of the sets being intersected (assuming you've proved $\varnothing \cap B=\varnothing$ for every set $B$).